# (Yii) Replace database values depending of a condition in CGridView

Tags: php, gridview, yii

I'm trying without success to get elements from a table of the database and show them in a Gridview depending of one condition.

Here is my code of the gridview:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id' => 'invoice-grid',
'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
'filter' => $model,
'columns' => array(     

    'number',
    'recipient_user_id',
    'recipientName',
    'recipientCompany',
     'type' => function($data, $row) {
                    if ($data->type == 1) { return "Hello"; } 
                    if ($data->type == 2) { return "Bye"; }
                    if ($data->type == 3) { return "Good"; }
                    if ($data->type == 4) { return "Milk"; }
                },
    'periodFrom',

    array(
        'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
        'template'=>'{view}',
    ),
),
```

)); ?>

It is still not working. Do you have another Idea?

Comment: Sorry. I finally found my error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry. I finally found my error. Normally I should have done :

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id' => 'invoice-grid',
'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
'filter' => $model,
'columns' => array(     

    'number',
    'recipient_user_id',
    'recipientName',
    'recipientCompany',

        array(
                'name'=>'type',
                'value'=>function($data, $row) {
                    if ($data->type == 1) { return "Hello"; } 
                    if ($data->type == 2) { return "Bye"; }
                    if ($data->type == 3) { return "Good"; }
                    if ($data->type == 4) { return "Milk"; }
                },

        ),

    'periodFrom',

    array(
        'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
        'template'=>'{view}',
    ),
),
```

)); ?>